# How do I create a numbered list that starts with a letter and new items are added in descending order?

Tags: lists

I am a beginner at LaTeX and one of the projects I'm using to teach myself has been to recreate my CV in LaTeX. I want to list my publications so that each category starts with a letter in the numbered list. For example journal articles would be j1. ; j3. ; j3. and so on. Whereas conference papers would be c1. ; c2. you get the point. I would like the items to be in descending order so my newest journal article would be j30. and the previous one j29. all the way to the first publication (oldest).

Appologies if this question has been asked previously. I searched around for an answer on this but I don't think I can phrase my search terms in a way that gets at what I am hoping to do. Thanks in advance for any pointers anyone can provide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labelling itself could be achieved very easily with `enumitem` package, but not the reversal of the list.

However, there's the `etaremune` package, which does the reversal (requires **two** compilation runs, however). The labelling is to be changed manually.

Since the first level of `enumerate` uses the `enumi` counter, `\theenumi` has to be redefined locally, for the separate journal etc. types.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etaremune}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{j\arabic{enumi}}
\begin{etaremune}
\item The journal of Brontosaurs
\item The journal of Tyrannosaurus Rex 
\item The journal of Stegosaurs
\item Applied Antrophology for Dinosaurs

\end{etaremune}

% Now the conference papers
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{c\arabic{enumi}}
\begin{etaremune}
\item The secret life of TeX.SX users?
\item Are questions about MathJax off-topic on TeX.SX ?
\end{etaremune}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much. I appreciate the explanation and examples. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user78355: You're welcome. Happy TeXing and have lot of fun with LaTeX and TeX.SX!